# Validate button must be clicked before closing workbook

Tags: vba, excel

If user changes/writes into excel sheet then he must click the validate button.If he changes data and tries to save/close excel,pop up must be show to the user. Simply I want to check whether used clicks validate button before closing the workbook. If a single letter is changed by user, user needs to click on validate button. After clicking on validate button ,if user again changes any data ,then too user must get warning that validate before saving/closing.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: use the BeforeClose event

Comment: What @Economist said. From the sounds of your description, it might be more efficient to just call the `Validate` code in `BeforeClose` instead of checking the whole sheet for changes, then calling `Validate` which (my understanding) would essentially check the whole sheet again. This way, you don't have to rely on the user to click a button at all..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not contain a question.

Comment: before_close event is getting triggered automatically when closing the excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to write out all the code for you but what you'll need to do is create an on-change worksheet(Or workbook if you'd prefer) process that sets a custom worksheet attribute or your preferred method of storing a value persisting between sessions. That process will run when anything in the worksheet changes and will be able to set the value of your value so that you know "there has been a change, I am now not validated"

Then you need to create a before save process that checks to see if that value is "not validated" or "validated" (false or true or what have you). You set that process to break the save event and present an error message when the value is "not validated" and allow it when it is "validated".

Then you create a validate button/whatever and a process that sets the value to "validated" (may want to check and only change when the value is not already "validated" but that's up to you).

Then you'll have a set of processes where when the sheet/book changes, the value becomes invalid and saving is prevented. When the validate button is selected, the validate process changes the value to validated and saving is allowed again.